# Inject CSS classes and JS scripts into React App

Tags: reactjs

I'm looking for general guideance and/or ideas on how to dynamicall add CSS and JS code into a React application. Here's the scenario:

- I have a basic e-commerce web app built with React
- I have a custom BE running with Mongo DB
- I have default styling for the site (scss)
- I want to have the ability to save some CSS files and JS files into the DB, and have the React app fetch those files and apply to the code

For example, let say the applications main container looks like this:

```html
<div className='main-container'>...</div>
```

With the following scss:

```css
.main-container {
   background-color: red;
}
```

What I want to do is have the following stylesheet saved in the DB, and have the app apply the styles on load

```css
.main-container {
   background-color: blue;
}
```

An example for custom JS injection would be the need to inject Google Analytics into the app in certain scenarios.

I'm looking for general direction or ideas on how this could be achieved (dynamic file injection, not how to fetch data from the DB for example).
Thanks in advance!

Haven't really done anything like this before so not really sure how to get started.

Comment: `script` elements need to be injected into `document.head` (anywhere else and they won't get parsed and executed). CSS can be injected anyhere as `link` element. But how you save them to the DB and read them back out is entirely up to you, so search the web for how to do that, because SO is your last resort, you get to do your own [(re)searching first](/help/how-to-ask). Only once you've run out of places to look does SO become the right place to ask. (Remember that SO is [not a general help forum](/help/on-topic), it's not for asking folks for implementation recommendations)